# Errors on multi-line equation with brackets

Tags: equations, amsmath, texstudio, brackets, eqnarray

I am running this code for an equation that runs over into the margins:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
        N(t,x) &=& \inf_{u_{I+1} \in [-u_{I+1}, w_{I+1}], T_{I+1} \in \Real_+} \left\{ \inf_{u_I \in [-u_I, w_I], T_I \in \Real_+} \left\{ c(t - T_I-T_{I+1}, x + T_Iu_I+T_{I+1}u_{I+1})\\          
        &+& T_I\varphi_I(u_I) + T_{I+1}\varphi_{I+1}(u_{I+1}) \right\} \right\} \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
```

Which gives:

[image]

and I keep getting myriad errors:

> ```
> Extra }, or forgotten \right. &
> Missing \right. inserted. &
> Missing \right. inserted. &
> Missing } inserted. &
> Missing } inserted. ..._I) + T_{I+1}\varphi_{I+1}(u_{I+1}) \right
> Extra \right. ...) + T_{I+1}\varphi_{I+1}(u_{I+1}) \right\}
> Extra \right. ...1}\varphi_{I+1}(u_{I+1}) \right\} \right\}
> Incomplete \ifcase; all text was ignored after line 64. \end{eqnarray}
> Missing $ inserted. \end{eqnarray}
> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{eqnarray}
> Extra \or. \end{eqnarray}
> Extra \or. \end{eqnarray}
> Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \reserved@a. \end{eqnarray}
> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{eqnarray}
> Extra \else. \end{eqnarray}
> Missing $$ inserted. \end{eqnarray}
> Too many columns in eqnarray environment. \end{eqnarray}
> Extra \fi. \end{eqnarray}
> ```

I am not sure how to extend the double brackets across two lines.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work (more or less), but your first line is too long:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
        N(t,x) &=& \inf_{u_{I+1} \in [-u_{I+1}, w_{I+1}], T_{I+1} \in \mathbf{R}_+} \left\{ \inf_{u_I \in [-u_I, w_I], T_I \in \mathbf{R}_+} \left\{ c(t - T_I-T_{I+1}, x + T_Iu_I+T_{I+1}u_{I+1})\right.\right.\\          
        &+& \left.\left.\vphantom{\inf_{u_I \in [-u_I, w_I], T_I \in \mathbf{R}_+}}T_I\varphi_I(u_I) + T_{I+1}\varphi_{I+1}(u_{I+1}) \right\} \right\} \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

You shall get this:

[image]

By the way, I urge you to [use `align` instead of `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/134805).

Comment: Thank you so much! It is interesting with the \vphantom. I will use align from now on :)

Comment: Please don't use `eqnarray`.

Comment: @Mico To whom was this written?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - To you. I know you wrote " I urge you to use `align` instead of `eqnarray`, but casual readers may well not notice this. Better not to use `eqnarray` at all...

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility with `geometry` and `\substack` + the `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}%
    N(t,x) = \inf_{\substack{u_{I+1} \in [-u_{I+1}, w_{I+1}],\\ T_{I+1} \in \mathbf{R}_+}} \Biggl\{ \inf_{\substack{u_I \in [-u_I, w_I],\\ T_I \in \mathbf{R}_+}} \Biggl\{\begin{aligned} c(t - T_I-T_{I+1}, x + T_Iu_I+T_{I+1}u_{I+1})\\
        {}+ T_I\varphi_I(u_I) + T_{I+1}\varphi_{I+1}(u_{I+1})
        \end{aligned} \Biggr\} \Biggr\}%
     \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the use of `\substack`. :-) I might be tempted to use a `gathered` environment for the material inside the inner curly brace, and I'd prefix `{}` to `+ T_I\varphi_I(u_I)` in order to get TeX to treat `+` as a binary rather than as a unary operator.

Comment: @Mico: Semantically, I prefer a right alignment. For the spacing of +, you're right, and I'll fix  it in a moment.  I was mislead because initially, I didn't remove the \vphantom, and moved the + afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

A variation of nice @Bernard answer with use `multlined` for right side of equation and `\left\{` and `\right\}` for outer brace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}%
N(t,x) = \inf_{\substack{u_{I+1} \in [-u_{I+1}, w_{I+1}],\\ T_{I+1} \in \mathbf{R}_+}}
            \left\{ \inf_{\substack{u_I \in [-u_I, w_I],\\ T_I \in \mathbf{R}_+}} \Biggl\{\begin{multlined} 
                    c(t - T_I-T_{I+1}, x + T_Iu_I+T_{I+1}u_{I+1})\\
                    {}+ T_I\varphi_I(u_I) + T_{I+1}\varphi_{I+1}(u_{I+1})
                    \end{multlined} \Biggr\} 
            \right\}
     \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]